# React App root div strange width on mobile devices

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a React app (not React Native). I worked on it in my browser, made it responsive etc. Now I wanted to check how it would look on mobile devices.

I was surprised to see this:

[image]

As you can see, the page header gets smaller and some elements like user avatar overflow it. This is particularly strange since the div I selected in dev tools is `root` - the one that all of the app content goes too (I've bootstrapped the project via `create-react-app`). So the navbar shrinks to the `root` div width, but the elements like the user avatar not - which is odd, since this is a grid and they should soon stack on top of each other, reorganize.

Now this works perfectly fine when I look at it normally in the browser, even if I shrink the page to like 150 pixels width - navbar covers page's full width, the elements are being organized properly.

I thought that it's maybe some device emulator bug, so I checked on my smartphone - no luck, pretty much the same thing as in here. So this is not like this white stripe would not be in the viewport, I can see it on my phone even if I maximally zoom my mobile chrome browser out.

What could cause that kind of thing?

P.S Same thing happens in Firefox

@Edit

`index.tsx` - here I access the `root` div

```
import App from "./containers/App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

`index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`App` component - I cut out the routes to reduce its size here:

```
const App = () => {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(isAuthenticated());
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState<UserData | null>(null);
  const classes = styles();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!loggedIn) {
      setCurrentUser(null);
      return;
    }
    const getUser = async () => {
      setCurrentUser(await getCurrentUser());
    };
    getUser();
  }, [loggedIn]);

  const logIn = () => {
    setLoggedIn(true);
  };
  const logOut = () => {
    setLoggedIn(false);
  };
  return (
    <Router>
      <S.PageContainer>
        <PageHeaderAD currentUser={currentUser} logOut={logOut} />
        <S.PageContent>
          <Switch>
            [...]
          </Switch>
        </S.PageContent>
      </S.PageContainer>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Containers used in App:

```
const PageContainer = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
`;

const PageContent = styled.div`
  flex: 1 1 auto;
`;
```

`PageHeaderAD` contains many things but it is wrapped in:

```
const PageHeader = styled.div`
  background: #3f51b5;
`;
```

Comment: can't tell unless you share the code

Comment: Done, added anything that could be of any significance - the problem persists on every page, so I've added `index.tsx` and my `App` component. I can add a `PageHeader` here but dunno if that would matter

Comment: Funny thing - kinda the same thing happens if I swap my Page header for a MUI one - I test those libraries in my project and currently have my components implemented in both versions

Comment: Same thing for just a simple div

Comment: @dabljues did you get this figured out? I've run into this a few times now.

Comment: I kinda stopped working on the project for a while but while I was working on it, I ditched the mobile checks, I wanted to implement all the features and then go checking if it works properly on mobile devices. So unfortunately no, I don't think I figured this out

Comment: This would be hard to pin point what is wrong, but likely a css issue. The search may have a min width set to it so it pushing it outside of the area. A way to tell if this is the case is to put an overflow-x as hidden, If it cuts off as i expect it will from the image, then look at the css for the page header. Start eliminating elements till it doesn't occur.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help, but maybe your case are not the same.
Becase I can not see your real **HTML** that components's renders

```html
<S.PageContainer>
        <PageHeaderAD currentUser={currentUser} logOut={logOut} />
        <S.PageContent>
          <Switch>
            [...]
          </Switch>
        </S.PageContent>
      </S.PageContainer>
```

---

After some research. I found that the reason(in my case) is in the `<span />` tag.

The `<span />` will **remain one line** of its content.

If your `<span />`'s font size is too large, it will force the browser to resize and cause this problem.

example:

```
<span style="text-align: left; font-size: 50px;"></span>
```

Because the `font-size` is 50px, so the span will let font size be 50px, at the mean time still remain **one line** of its content.
The result will be like this (an image form my project)
[image]

#### Solution

My solution is to change the fontSize by `vh` unit. Let the fontSize change with the height of screen.
[image]